# How do you disable the INSPECT ELEMENT option in the menu from Chrome and Firefox etc?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, firebug

I actually like and use Firebug for web development every single day; sure it is slow on boot for Firefox but I love Firebug once the browser is up. (Update this has been resolved in later editions)

Firefox 10 has a new Inspect and developer mode - it is pretty much like Google Chrome - I don't like it, you cannot edit on page CSS, you can't edit text and tags simply like Firebug - I would be on Chrome now if it fully had Firebug.

How can I disable firefox inspect?
How can I disable the inspect mode in chrome? (I would rather use the light firebug)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

type in `about:config` in your address bar and find `devtools.inspector.enabled` and set it to `false`

Comment: Works! Thank you. I thought I would have to restart browser. Updated my Question...