# How to remove Firefox's "inspect element" button?

Tags: firefox, firebug

This is driving me crazy! When FF 12 came out, Firefox's own 'Inspect Element' button on the right-click menu took the place of there the Firebug 'Inspect Element' button used to be.

As I've been doing web development in Firefox forever, my muscle memory still clicks there when I want to use Firebug.

[image: My right-click menu]

Is there any way to remove the Firefox internal 'Inspect Element' and replace the button on the menu with Firebug's, returning it to its original position (marked `NO` in the screenshot)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

***Revisited in Oct. 2019***: Both add-ons seem to be gone now, using 
`devtools.inspector.enabled` setting in [`about:config`](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/about-config-editor-firefox) would be the best way to do this.

***Revisited in Nov. 26 2014***: Menu Editor seems to be deprecated. [Menu Wizard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/s3menu-wizard/) looks like a good alternative.

Yes!

1. Install the [Menu Editor addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/menu-editor/)
2. Open the options of Menu editor, make sure you are editing the Main context menu and then hide the inspect element entry

[image: Menu editor options]
 3. Drag the Firebug inspect option up to where you would like it
 4. ???
 5. Profit!

Comment: @Canha THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!! My profit has gone through the roof!

Comment: No worries @CamelBlues, be happy!

Comment: +1 for  noticing you answer was deprecated and updating it!

Answer (score 7):

This is not needed. As referenced: [How do you disable the INSPECT ELEMENT option in the menu from Chrome and Firefox etc?](https://superuser.com/questions/389933/how-do-i-disable-firefox-10-inspect-mode-and-google-chrome-inspect-mode)

Type in `about:config` in your address bar and find `devtools.inspector.enabled` and set it to `false`

Comment: No excess baggage installed to slow the system down and require updates every time you turn around.

Comment: Do you mean method is slow? Please explain the reason if so..

Comment: If it is a config setting in the browser, and you point that out, it is better to use that, than install some addon (as in the other answers) that sticks unneeded code into the system. Your recommendation won't be needing a periodic upgrade. Or be adding code that needs to be executed every time something happens that it has to monitor, eh?

Comment: Yes I thought you were saying that I was in the wrong. Thanks for explaining. Hope I get answer on SU. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Starting in Firebug 1.10, there is [a Firebug setting](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5551) that blocks the native Inspect Element menu item:

```
extensions.firebug.hideDefaultInspector
```

So, if you want it blocked, go to `about:config` in your address bar and toggle this to `true`.

If you want to see the native "Inspect Element" menu entry either disable/uninstall Firebug or toggle this to `false` in `about:config`.

Comment: Incredible! This answer should be accepted instead other one. `about:config` is good.

Comment: @NNToan  `about:config` is better than this. That doesn't not depend anything.